# Alternative for "LIMIT" in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Does 'LIMIT' works in elastic search? If no, what can be alternative to restrict the results in elastic search as LIMIT wont work here.
If yes, how to use it in proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use From/Size in ElasticSearch to limit the results.

Please check the below link for further details.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/search-request-from-size.html#search-request-from-size